# `Launchd` based logging - where does `log show` get its data from

Tags: macos, logging, launchd

I would like my logs to show up when I do something like this

```
log show --debug --info | grep "Myapp"
```

I am currently doing something like this in `launchd` which writes to a flat file.

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/app/s.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/app/e.log</string>
```

I would like to know how I can adjust the above so that my logs can be shown using `log show`. Is there a specific path that `log show` commands reads its contents from ?

Primarily what I would like to do is adjust the above `launchd` snippet so that the output gets sent to system logs and I am not sure which files are read and displayed there

Comment: Not enough context. What do you mean by "show up"? where, in a shell in Terminal? in the Console app's window? in a text-file? in a log-database? In your own UI?

`log show` EVALUATES log messages from the os_log binary database. It doesn't merely "show" them. Your command costly and slow. Instead of evaluating the whole Mac log then filter your "Myapp" - provide 'log show' with a QUERY to only show your app's log messages.  Next, I can't understand why launchd. launchd is a MacOS subsystem used for launching and maintaining jobs (daemons and agents), not for "showing up" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

To see your logs in `log show` you must first WRITE your logs to the `os_log` system.

You have not provided any context about your objective -- not even what kind of software you're writing. I don't know why you introduced the word "launchd" in your question - as if it relates somehow to the logging system (it's not).

Provided that you write your software in C or Objective-C or C++ -- then you'll need to import <os_log/os_log.h> into your code, and learn how to

1. create a log object
2. emit log lines in your code

Then - your logs will appear in Log-show.

If you're writing in swift - its about the same.

Other than that -- I'll need more information to help you specifically.